# How do I fix object collision points?

Tags: mesh, collision, rigidbody

I'm having an issue where my object stops before it collides with its intended point, it is almost like it's running into the mesh, but it's not and I'm not sure how to fix it.[image]

Comment: Hi there, this is a very broad question that is very specific to your setup. It would help greatly if you attach your .blend file to your question. You can do that here -> https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Please show your collision settings.

Comment: It would help if you shared your file